# SQL Server - convert string to elapsed, time, return max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, duration

I have a set of values like:

```
TrackUserId EventTime                 EventName     EventValue
---------------------------------------------------------------------
643812      2019-10-05 00:26:38.513   time.today    00:40:55.9443418
643806      2019-10-04 23:51:43.577   time.today    00:02:33.6620074
643806      2019-10-04 23:52:30.610   time.today    00:13:04.3645199
```

The `EventValue` is a string (the database is name value pairs where the value "type" is dependent on the name). The values here are durations, not time of day.
It may write the duration for a specific `TrackUserId` multiple times during the day, each value being duration this day so far. So the values keep increasing.

Note that there are 2 entries for TrackUserId=643806 and in this case I want the second one as it is the longer duration.

For a given `TrackUserId` and `EventTime` day (ie by date, not datetime), I want to get one row back, the row with the largest elapsed time. Is this possible?

Comment: All your rows have different values for `EventTime`, so your conditions on this example would result in the three rows you have specified.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match the description.

Comment: @ZoharPeled How does it not match? The EventName and EventValue columns are both varchar.

Comment: You wrote the value is increasing, but in the sample data it's decreasing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry, fixed (I wrote in dummy data).

Comment: @DavidThielen . . . Your question is inconsistent.  Either you want one row  per `TrackUserId` or one row per `TrackUserId`/`EventTime`.  You explicitly state you want the latter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, now I understand the confusion. For the EventTime, I want the larges value for each day. So by the date component of the datetime value - 2019-10-04. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select TrackUserId, EventTime, max(EventValue)
from t
where EventName = 'time.today'
group by TrackUserId, EventTime;
```

For your data sample, this is unnecessary because all the event times are different, so you just want those three rows.

If you want the most recent row per `TrackUserId`, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.EventName = 'time.today' and
      t.EventTime = (select max(t2.EventTime)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.TrackUserId = t.TrackUserId and
                           t2.EventName = 'time.today'
                    );
```

You can adjust this for a day:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.EventName = 'time.today' and
      t.EventTime = (select max(t2.EventTime)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.TrackUserId = t.TrackUserId and
                           convert(date, t2.eventTime) = convert(date, t1.eventTime) and
                           t2.EventName = 'time.today'
                    );
```

Comment: There are 2 entries for TrackUserId=643806 so I want just the second of those. I tried your select but it returned all three.

Comment: Gordon's answer gives the exact result you described - one row per TrackUserId and EventTime. You should probably edit your question again if that's not what you want.